# jQuery UI datepicker not working with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am trying to install the jQuery UI Datepicker for my Rails application based on: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails, as well as the Revised Railscast on this topic and countless threads trying to get this working. No matter what I try it does not seem to work.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require_tree .
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

**application.css**

```
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

**new.html.erb**

```
  <%= f.label :due_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :due_date %>
```

**modelname.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
$('#modelname_due_date').datepicker (dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy')
```

This seems to be all I need to make this work, however I have tried many variations to no avail. There are no errors thrown to the console when debugging in Chrome. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the console(Chrome Dev tools), any errors?

Comment: No errors are being thrown to the console, it simply does nothing when I click into the text field.

Comment: after page load, can you try the javascript statement to create datepicker in chrome chosole ? i.e. $('#modelname_due_date').datepicker (dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy') Then try to focus of text field. If that works then something is wrong in loading component, if that's not then something is missing / wrong to create datepicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to give a class to your input field , like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :due_date,class: "modelname_due_date %>
```

In case of using class selector, javascript code should be changed:

```
$('.modelname_due_date').datepicker (dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy')
```

Then you will have javascript code triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The class name is now added to my field, unfortunately the datepicker is still not working :(

Comment: Check your Gemfile for `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`. What is exactly your Model name?

Comment: Gem is there. Model name is simply 'project'. So class name and id is 'project_due_date'.

Comment: Somehow it now works. I completely shut down my server, re-ran bundle update and 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile'. Anyway thanks for all of the helpful replies.

Comment: @RumenMilushev , any idea how to fix this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336585/rails-jquery-datepicker-not-working