# jQuery UI datepicker with foundation and form_tag not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker, zurb-foundation

I'm a beginner with jQuery and I'm trying to implement a datepicker. I have the `jquery-ui-rails` gem in my Gemfile. I'm using foundation and my form is:

```
<div class="row search-area">
  <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "From", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= text_field_tag(:start_date, params[:start_date], :class => "date-field") %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "To", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= text_field_tag(:end_date, params[:end_date], :class => "date-field") %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-1 large-1 columns search-field">
    <%= label_tag "Guests", nil, class: "right inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 columns search-field">
    <%= number_field(:number_of_guests, params[:number_of_guests], in: 1.0..20.0, step: 1.0) %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns">
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :class => "button" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In `application.js` I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

$(function() {
  $('.date-field').datepicker();
});
```

And in `application.css.scss` I have:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require jquery-ui
 */

 @import "foundation_and_overrides";
```

The problem is that my text fields stay as text fields and no calendar pops up when I click on them.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153587/jquery-ui-datepicker-not-working-with-rails) I tried stopping my server, running `bundle update` and then running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. This did not work.

I also tried to do a bit of digging around with the developer tools in Chrome. When I inspect the text-field element that's supposed to show the datepicker calendar and then click on 'sources' in developer tools, there's an 'app/jquery-ui' folder with a whole lot of css files. When I click on 'network' and reload the page the only javascript file I see is 'modernizr.self.js' which is apparently located in 'assets/vendor/'.

Does this mean that somehow the jquery-ui javascripts are not being compiled? If so how do I fix this?

After a bit of searching and further debugging - I think the problem might be with [the asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504702/asset-pipeline-application-js-not-compiled-loaded) and that `application.js` is not being seen at all.

Comment: If there re multiple css files associated with jquery-ui, then you need to make sure you require_tree jquery-ui (if app/jquery-ui is a folder.)

Comment: In my actual project there's just an app/javascripts folder but when I inspect the text field element I want the datepicker to show in then in developer tools under sources theres an app/jquery-ui folder. Do I still need `\\=require_tree jquery-ui`?

Comment: Ah! My bad. Didn't read more closely into your question. If you're using a datepicker/calendar, you need to include the specific module. See the Github here: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails. So you need to //= require jquery-ui/datepicker in your application.js and *= require jquery-ui/datepicker in your application.css.

Comment: That doesn't help I'm afraid :( I tried stopping my server and precompiling my assets again as well but the text boxes are still staying as plain text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You may call datepicker, when document is ready. Like following code.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.date-field').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately the calendar is still not showing. I'm still seeing plain text boxes.

Comment: can you run this `$('.date-field').datepicker();` in your browser console? And, see if `datepicker` is applied

Comment: This is what I get: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:18
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)`

Comment: Its running at my side, try only include `//= require_tree .` and remove other files.

Comment: Nope no change. It's very important that I get this working. Any idea what could be the problem on my side? I'm very new to working with javascript/jQuery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89182/discussion-between-sarwan-kumar-and-sosimple).