# Asset pipeline - application.js not compiled/loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm using rails 4 with foundation 5 and I'm having trouble getting javascript to work. Foundation's navbar menu doesn't drop down in mobile and I'm having trouble [getting the jQuery datepicker to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481524/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-foundation-and-form-tag-not-working). After a bit of searching on this site and on Google, I thought the problem might be that I was using sprockets version 2.1.2. However, after upgrading (now at version 3.3.4) the problem still hasn't been solved.

I removed everthing in `application.js` and added a function to simple append one div to another to check if the file is being loaded so `application.js` now looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#test').append("<div class='test'>Test</div>");
});
```

Unfortunately, the `div` does not get appended. I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm not sure what else I can do to figure out why no javascript is being loaded. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

**More Info**

When I try to navigate to `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js` I get the following:

> throw Error("Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'self' with
>   type 'application/javascript'\n  (in
>   /home/sheeka/Documents/workspace/my_projects/ruby/technical_tests/homestay/homestay_test/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:17)")

I've no problem bringing up `application.css.scss` in a similar manner but I'm not entirely sure what this means.

As requested: [Github repo](https://github.com/sheekap/test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in the docs at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

You need to include a `require_self` in your application.js file.
Without it the functions in this file will not be loaded.

**Update**

1. In your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` change `//= require self` to `//= require_self`
2. Your `$(document).ready` functions are not being loaded because the  [turbolinks gem](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).
   In your application layout change this line:
   `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`
   To
   `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

But if you want to keep it, take a look in this gem: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

There are a few differences that you need to know when you are working with turbolinks, so please take a look in his docs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: at least your div was appended inside your `#test` element?

Comment: No, it wasn't. My test element only contains a form that was there before I started trying to debug js

Comment: @SoSimple if it is possible, please post your code on github or somewhere, then we can take a look

Comment: sorry for the delay, I've updated my question with a link to the github repository.

Comment: omfg, that simple? I feel like a complete tool now :P Thanks so much for your help!